# Prevent Personal Information autofill

Tags: html, chromium, autofill

How to prevent chromium based browser from sugesting personal information autofill for specific input?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="Nomenclature"> Nomenclature</label>
    <input name="Nomenclature" class="form-control" id="Nomenclature" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

Somehow MS Edge assume this input is personal information, but it's not. As you can see, autocomplete is off for this input, so I guess Personal Information don't respect this attribute.

This behaviour is very annoying for users, because this input must be unique.

There are also other inputs in my portal that have this behaviour, and it makes no sense to users.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disabling Chrome Autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill)

Comment: No, it's not autofill, it's personal information autofill

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `autocomplete="off"` with form

More details:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

Comment: I already have that (form and input). The autofill is done by chromium "Personal Information" feature.